# DIV being pushed down in IE7 - can't figure out why

Tags: html, css

See http://www.jciuk.org.uk/events/

In IE 7 the main content column is being pushed down and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `MARGIN: -500px 0px 0px 280px;` - I checked in DebugBar and it seems to have mysterious margin which isn't in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ie7.css file, just change the value of your negative margins:

```
.events_right_index
{
    margin: -590px 0 0 280px !important;
}
```

I would attempt to explain this, but this is IE7, and you've already got a conditional style sheet for it, so you might as well use it.

Comment: This is not a very robust solution as the -590px is being calculated based on the current height of the sidebar. If the content of the sidebar were to ever change or be dynamic, this solution would no longer be correct.

Comment: Thanks - that's sorted it. This is not my favourite cutup! Not my doing.

Answer (score 2):

Set width to auto for IE7. Like this:

`#events_right{width:auto;}`

It will work.

Comment: Also, You don't have to specify `margin-top` to negative value to do that, I saw that in your IE7 specific css.

Comment: Thanks - I've accepted the other answer as that's what I've implemented and got working. Thanks for the assistance though!